# How can I get facts from my knowledge base into a list?

Tags: prolog, prolog-setof

Say I have these facts:

```
person(fred).
person(jim).
person(mary).

is_person(person(_)).
```

I would like to get a list like:

```
[person(fred), person(jim), person(mary)]
```

but my query with `findall/3` does not give the expected result:

```
?- findall(Person,is_person(Person),ListOfPeople).
ListOfPeople = [person(_5034)].
```

Similarly with `bagof/3`:

```
?- bagof(Person,is_person(Person),ListOfPeople).
ListOfPeople = [person(_5940)].
```

I do not understand why `findall/3` and `bagof/3` behave like this.

Comment: Use [bagof/3](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=bagof/3)

Comment: If you are quick you can answer your own question and get more points. :)

Comment: bagof/3 is giving me the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way:

```
findall(person(Person),person(Person),ListOfPeople).
```

or

```
bagof(person(Person),person(Person),ListOfPeople).
```

Why doesn't your approach work? Consider

```
findall(Person,is_person(Person),ListOfPeople).
```

Prolog tries to fulfill `is_person(Person)`.

There is a fact `is_person(person(_)).`

So, for `Person = person(_)`, we are good! So `person(_)` will be in the list.

And that's all, there are no other ways to derive `is_person(Person)`.

To collect all the `Person`, we really need to ask for the `Person` which fulfills `person(Person)`.

Thus:

```
findall(person(Person),person(Person),ListOfPeople).
```

Prolog will find three `Person` which fulfill `person(Person)`. As the result should not be a list of `Person` but of `person(Person)` we slap a `person/1` around `Person` in the 1st parameter, the template.

Alternatively (but a bit pointlessly), you could:

```
is_person(person(X)) :- person(X).

?- findall(X,is_person(X),ListOfPeople).
```

Here, Prolog collects all the `X` for which `is_person(person(X))`, which are all the `X` which appear in a (fact) `person(X)`. Thus `X` is for example `fred`. We slap a `person/1` around `fred` in the head of `is_person/1`. Done.

Comment: findall/3 has some subtle problems (Richard O'Keefe's "Craft of Prolog" describes them); I would suggest bagof/3 or setof/3. Also, watch out for free variables. Some edge cases are mentioned here: https://swi-prolog.discourse.group/t/findall-3-and-overlapping-use-of-variable-names/3309

Comment: @PeterLudemann Thanks Peter. I wrote them up here: [About findall/3](https://github.com/dtonhofer/prolog_notes/tree/master/swipl_notes/about_findall). I actually didn't look at O'Keefe's book. I shall take a look.